# Accessing variables from template file in ansible

Tags: variables, ansible, jinja2

I have a task:

```
- name: Copy celeryconfig.py to "proj_dir/monitor/"
  copy:
    src="templates/repo/celeryconfig.py.j2"
    dest={{proj_dir}}/monitor/celeryconfig.py 
  run_once: true
```

Variables that is stored it vars\mail.yml. Inside this file I have rabbitmq_app_user, rabbitmq_app_pass, rabbitmq_app_vhost are defined.

And template file:

```
BROKER_URL = "apmq://{{rabbitmq_app_user}}:{{rabbitmq_app_pass}}@IP/{{rabbitmq_app_vhost}}"
```

But when I run the playbook, result looks exactly same as what in inside the template file. Seems the way I try to access to variables that are defined in /vars/main.yml is incorrect. What's the proper way of accessing to variables in my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use jinja template in Ansible you have to use the [template](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html) module as well. Try something like this:

```
- name: Copy celeryconfig.py to "proj_dir/monitor/"
  template:
    src: "repo/celeryconfig.py.j2"
    dest: "{{ proj_dir }}/monitor/celeryconfig.py"
  run_once: true
```

Comment: Oh my bad... There were multiple task that uses copy module and I forgot to change it to template module. Thanks! :)